# Is there anything like share ionic app content with intent?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want intent share like android i.e from my ionic app i can share some content with intent where all the installed apps will show in share list and i can chose any of them to share the content.

Comment: you want to share content or your App

Comment: Check this out https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/

Comment: i want to share the content from the app @sunielkalwani

Comment: i already check that link but it's not the sharing what i want. if you follow the android intent share then you can find that functionality that i wanted. @hrdkisback

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin